# How to get the expiration date of Facebook Account Kit Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, facebook-access-token, account-kit

I have an Android application with Account Kit for SMS authentication and it creates a TOKEN that expires after a few weeks but I want to know when.

In the documentation it is said how to check if a token is valid or not:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi/#at-validation?

```
GET https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.3/me/?access_token=<access_token>
```

but how to know the expiry date of a token? I searched and found no way.

In this doc it said how to get the expiration date with the Debug Tool but I think it's for Facebook graph API token and not account kit which is different, because I test it and I get always "Malformed token" :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling?

In Android I can get the Last Refresh and the Refresh Interval in seconds but not the expiry date:

Token last refresh => Mon Nov 12 02:33:19 GMT+01:00 2018

Token refresh interval in seconds => 2592000 (1 month)

How to know the expiry date of a token Account kit? and how to get it never expired? does that mean that the token expires 1 month after the last refresh?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Well if you know it was last refreshed on Monday, November 12, and you got the info how long the refresh interval is – don’t you have all the info you need already?

Comment: I'm not sure, does the "Refresh Interval in seconds" mean that the token will expire December 12 ? but the problem is that the user must launch the application itself to refresh the token, I would like to refresh the token remotely, so that the session does not expire for the user even if he does not connect for 1 month !

Comment: That’s not how this works, you can not refresh user tokens without user interaction. What would you need a fresh token for, if the user has not visited/used your app for over a month?